# Should I check for updated attributes before making a db call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

On an update action is it worth seeing if any of the record's attributes have changed before making a db call to update the record? A call would still have to be made to look up the record.

I plan to not make calls to the api in the first place unless the user updates an attribute, but didn't know if it was good to put a guard in the action itself. This is using Rails and PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails/Activerecord will be taking care of making sure it updates when it's really needed and if attributes have [changed?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changed-3F) . Here is a example via console

Case when **record is not changed**. Update query is not made

```
    [9] pry(main)> user  = User.last
     User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
    => #<User:0x007fee16801108 ...>
    [10] pry(main)> user.save
    (0.1ms)  begin transaction #<====== NO UPDATE QUERY IS MADE
    (0.0ms)  commit transaction
=> true
[11] pry(main)>
```

Case when **record is changed**. Update query is made

```
[12] pry(main)> user  = User.last
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<User:0x007fee12c02558 id: 1,...?
[13] pry(main)> user.name = 'f'
=> "f"
[14] pry(main)> user.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction #<====== UPDATE QUERY IS MADE
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "name" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["name", "f"], ["updated_at", "2017-10-19 06:56:51.385277"], ["id", 1]]
"complete"
   (2.2ms)  commit transaction
=> true
[15] pry(main)>
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how exactly to do the update.

ActiveRecord won't do the actual update at the DB if the model isn't [dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html).

You can compare the update_at value before and after the update, and trigger the API only if it was changed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you need.

**Firstly**, ***if its just one column***,As in my case, i just wanted to check a single attribute..state of the model..so i used [workflow gem.](https://github.com/geekq/workflow)..and i added model callbacks only when that attribute changed like this...

```
##workflow_state is my column name
after_save :update_other_associations_status , if: :workflow_state_changed?
```

Moreover, you can also use `column_was` eg.. `workflow_state_was` to check the old value before saving it in the db.I would recommend to have a look at [**ActiveModel::Dirty**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) module

**Secondly**, ***if you want to check multiple values of a model***, you can go with the awesome [papertrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail), which monitors entire model and its highly configurable as when and where you need to catch the changes in the versions of the model.

Hope this helps